# Java: thread stops despite exception handling

Tags: java, multithreading, exception

I use a Timer.schedule() to periodically call the run() method of the TimerTask class to poll devices. Sometimes a MalformedJsonException or a IllegalStateException are thrown, which is processed in the catch block. The thread should continue to poll devices after handling the exception, but it stops.
When there are no errors, the run method is periodically called as expected.
I also tried calling the runModulesPoll() method from the catch block, but that didn't help.

```
private static void runModulesPoll(Boiler boiler) {
        new Timer("Modules Poll Flow").schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Module[] modules = boiler.getCore().getModules();
                    for (Module module : modules) {
                        String response = ControllersService.sendMessage(MessageBuilder.buildDataRequest(module.getAlias(), boiler.getBoilerMode()));
                        if (AppUtils.isStringInvalid(response)) {
                            module.setOnline(false);
                            ModulesResetService.reset();
                            continue;
                        }
                        module.setOnline(true);
                        module.fromShortJson(response);
                    }
                    MqttService.publishMessage(MqttMessageFactory.createDataMessage(boiler.getCore().getModulesDataAsJson()));
                } catch (Throwable e) {
                    LoggerLocal.error("Exception in Modules Poll Flow: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, 0, 1);
    }
```

According to the logs, the exception is handled as expected, but the thread does not continue polling.

```
    14-11-2019 18:10:47 -- Exception in Modules Poll Flow: Not a JSON Object: "hgjhgjhg"
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not a JSON Object: "hgjhgjhg"
    at com.google.gson.JsonElement.getAsJsonObject(JsonElement.java:90)
    at eezo.AppUtils.getJsonObjectFromString(AppUtils.java:101)
    at eezo.services.ControllersService.handleIfErrorMessage(ControllersService.java:148)
    at eezo.services.ControllersService.sendMessage(ControllersService.java:53)
    at eezo.ApplicationRunner$1.run(ApplicationRunner.java:107)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
```

**UPDATE:**
Exception throws inside try block and handles in catch but thread stops without any other exceptions.
LoggerLocal doesn't produce exceptions at all.

I simulated the situation with a simpler example and everything works as expected, the thread does not fall and handles exceptions constantly.

```
private static void run(String[] args) {
    final int[] i = {0};
    new Timer("Modules Poll Flow").schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                System.out.println("run() " + args);
                if (i[0] == 5) throw new IllegalStateException("ssss");
                i[0]++;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Exception in Modules Poll Flow: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, 0, 1);
}
```

Comment: Is this the code that produced that stack trace? That would be hard to conceive since your exception is clearly propagated beyond your anonymous class's `run()` method - and that can't happen with `catch(Throwable)` that doesn't rethrow.

Comment: maybe `LoggerLocal` is rethrowing the exception

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger then the `LoggerLocal` class would be in the stack trace

Comment: @ernest_k isn't the stack trace reflecting when the exception was created? (Throwable: "A throwable contains a snapshot of the execution stack of its thread at the time it was created.")

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger Good point. But the `LoggerLocal.error` method doesn't take the exception object `e`, so it wouldn't possibly rethrow it.

Comment: @ernest_k I stay corrected... somehow I assumed the exception was being passed

Comment: Maybe there is something wrong with `ControllersService` (or other class you use), which freezes when there is an exception. When there is a running thread, which is not finished, the timer won't generate a new thread. When it happens, try to generate "dump thread" which shows all the app threads state (using jstack, or the camera button if you have intellij).